# sprites compass - cannot resolve import to SASS

Tags: sass, спрайт, compass

В папке images появилась картинка со спрайтами, но в SASS файле у меня высвечивается ошибка с `@import "icons/*.png";` с текстом: ***cannot resolve import to SASS/SCSS file***.
Также ошибка в `@include all-icons-sprites;` с текстом: ***there is an error as cannot find mixin "all-icons-sprites"***

Структура моих папок

- images

  - icons

    - icon_1.png
    - icon_2.png
    - icon_3.png
    - icon_4.png

config.rb

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
http_fonts_path = "../fonts"
asset_cache_buster :none
relative_assets = true
```

SASS

```
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";
@import "icons/*.png";
@include all-icons-sprites;
```

CSS output

```
.icons-sprite, .icons-icon_1, .icons-icon_2, .icons-icon_3, .icons-icon_4, .icons-icons-sc0b61509a6 {
background-image: url('../images/icons-s705cc83f98.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Если в SASS файле я меняю эту строчку, ошибка исчезает

```
@import "../images/icons/*.png";
```

Но в CSS теперь отображается неправильный путь

```
background-image: url('../images/../images/icons-s3809f1281e.png');
```

Уже второй день пытаюсь понять, что не так, но безуспешно. Помогите пожалуйста.